# making HTTP post request with confirmation message for delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to delete an item by getting confirmation from user & I want to delete it with POST method.

Here's my code snippet

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete",new { id=item.UserId },new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Do you really want to delete this?"})
```

& my action method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id, LearningMVC.Models.User userDetails)
    {
        try
        {
            var dbContext = new MyDBDataContext();
            var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(userId => userId.UserId == id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                dbContext.Users.DeleteOnSubmit(user);
                dbContext.SubmitChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

If I remove the [HttpPost] attribute, It just deletes the record without any confirmation. It's giving 404 error with [HttpPost] attribute.
I have included jquery-1.5.1.min.js, unobtrusive-ajax.js, MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js in the said order in layout page.

what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you wanted to write:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",
    new { id = item.UserId },
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Do you really want to delete this?" })
```

Just use `AjaxHelper` instead of `HtmlHelper`.

Comment: This is working fine, i.e. deleting record with confirmation from user. But, I am deleting it being in Index view, then I am using 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

so the deleted item still exists in the index page. I mean it's not reloading/refreshing the index view. Can you suggest a way, how to achieve it?

Comment: Page is not refreshed, because you perform ajax call. Also, redirect response will not take effect. You should either return url for redirection in your response and make redirect in JavaScript, or simply don't use ajax.

Comment: I tried this "You should either return url for redirection in your response and make redirect in JavaScript". But, faced some issue.. the fresh question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546704/reload-index-view-after-deleting-a-record-on-it-on-ajax-call