# Reload index view after deleting a record on it on ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have list of items on index view & a delete button corresponding to each item. I want to delete a record with confirmation from end user. Record is getting deleted with confirmation from db but still exists on UI. So I created a shared view named "IndexReloader". which is returned after deleting & in this view I am reloading the index view. Here's my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? Id)
    {
        SqlConnection ObjSqlCon = null;
        try
        {
            var SqlQuery = @"DELETE FROM [USER] WHERE USERID = " + Id;

            var ConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MVCConnectionString"];
            // create a connection object
            ObjSqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr.ToString());

            // create a command object
            var ObjSqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, ObjSqlCon);
            // open the connection
            ObjSqlCon.Open();

            ObjSqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //return View("IndexReloader");
            return View("~/Views/Shared/IndexReloader.cshtml");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ObjSqlCon != null)
            {
                ObjSqlCon.Close(); ObjSqlCon.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

The IndexReloader view,

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IndexReloader</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //location.reload();
            alert("hey");
            window.location.replace("http://localhost/LearningMVC/My/Index.cshtml");
        });

</script>
</head>
```

In master page I have included jquery script files. I want my index view to be loaded with latest data as soon as I delete a record. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend not reloading the page.  with jquery you can hide or remove the item (table row, li, etc,  however you show the data) that your ajax call has deleted to keep the ui and the database in sync

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial view instead of a share view. If you want to reload the page (without ajax) you could redirect to the same action where you have the index page so will redirect to the same page with a simple POST

If you want it better, you could create a partialview inside your Indexreloader.cshml for the data shown. (Better if it's a Index.cshtml of some controller instead of a shared view)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View("Index");  //This could go in any controller you have
}
```

Then inside you Index.cshtml you could call a partialview

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!--some stuff you want -->  
<div id="ListItems">
    @{Html.RenderAction("PartialViewAction","Controller");}
</div>
```

Then in you controller you could do something like this:

```
public PartialViewResult PartialViewAction()
{
    //code stuff to return to the view, your list items
    return PartialView("_YourIndexData");
}
```

Your partial view you can create it as you like, all the items you need from database and use your model or viewmodel on the partialview will render on your Index.cshtml
And then your partialview if you want to send the the ID to delete the record you could use some ajax:

```
$("#Button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("DeleteAction","Controller")",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { id : "YourId" },
            success: function (result) {
               //Here you can call your partialview with your query in the controller
                var url = "@Url.Action("PartialViewAction", "Controller")";
                //If you need a parameter you can use this code to replace it via javascript    
                //url = url.replace("-dummy", JavascriptVariable);
                //The div ID in your Index.cshtml
                $("#ListItems").load(url)


            }
        });

         return false;
    });
```

In this case im using a "#Button" on click function. If you are using a list of items in your partial view you could create a link in you list items like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="YourJavascriptFunction(@Model.YourID)">Delete</a>
```

And then you could create a javascript function with the same code above:

```
function Yourfunction(ID){
     //AJAX CODE HERE
}
```

Hope this helps a little. Good luck.